# Making changes to future object

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11

I am trying to change the behavior of a future object based on user input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

//=======================================================================================!
struct DoWork
{

    DoWork(int cycles, int restTime) : _cycles(cycles), _restTime(restTime), _stop(false)
    {
    }

    void operator () ()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < _cycles; ++i)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(_restTime));
            if(_stop)break;

            doTask();
        }
    }

    void stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
    }

private:
    void doTask()
    {
        std::cout << "doing task!" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int _cycles;
    int _restTime;
    bool _stop;
};

//=======================================================================================!

int main()
{
    DoWork doObj(50, 500);
    std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async, doObj);

    std::cout << "Should I stop work ?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "('1' = Yes, '2' = no, 'any other' = maybe)" << std::endl;
    int answer;
    std::cin >> answer;

    if(answer == 1) doObj.stop();

    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
//=======================================================================================!
```

However this does not stop the execution of the future object. How do I change the behavior of the doObj after I have created the future object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems. First, your function object doesn't actually return `int`, so `std::async` will return a `std::future<void>`. You can fix this either by actually returning `int` from `DoWork::operator()`, or by storing the result from `async` in a `std::future<void>` and not trying to print it.

Second, `std::async` copies its arguments if they aren't in reference wrappers, so the `doObj` on the stack is not going to be the same instance of `DoWork` that is being used by the asynchronous thread. You can correct this by passing `doObj` in a reference wrapper a la `std::async(std::launch::async, std::ref(doObj))`.

Third, both the main thread and the asynchronous thread are simultaneously accessing `DoWork::_stop`. This is a data race and means the program has undefined behavior. The fix is to protect accesses to `_stop` with a `std::mutex` or to make it a `std::atomic`.

Altogether, program should look like ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e3a5a3692e3ff0a)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

//=======================================================================================!
struct DoWork
{
    DoWork(int cycles, int restTime) : _cycles(cycles), _restTime(restTime), _stop(false)
    {
    }

    int operator () ()
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < _cycles; ++i)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(_restTime));
            if(_stop) return 42;

            doTask();
        }
        return 13;
    }

    void stop()
    {
        _stop = true;
    }

private:
    void doTask()
    {
        std::cout << "doing task!" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int _cycles;
    int _restTime;
    std::atomic<bool> _stop;
};

//=======================================================================================!

int main()
{
    DoWork doObj(50, 500);
    std::future<int> f = std::async(std::launch::async, std::ref(doObj));

    std::cout << "Should I stop work ?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "('1' = Yes, '2' = no, 'any other' = maybe)" << std::endl;
    int answer;
    std::cin >> answer;

    if(answer == 1) doObj.stop();

    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;
}
//=======================================================================================!
```